# How do you access the command line boot menu when not dual booting?

Tags: boot, grub

Elementary OS is the only OS I have installed on my laptop.  So I don't get a GRUB boot menu.  If I need to boot to the command line I typically hit E when the boot menu shows up, but since it goes straight to elementary OS this E option does not work.

How do I access the terminal to do stuff while booting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pres `Esc` key once before the elementary logo appears.
Or, if you're not fast enough, edit grub file:

`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

Comment (place a `#` before) the two timeout lines, just like in the image bellow:

[image]

`Ctrl` + `o` to save the modifications

`Ctrl` + `x` to exit nano

`sudo update-grub`

`sudo reboot`

Now you'll get the GRUB screen, with a 5 seconds delay and you'll be able to do your thing. To revert, just un-comment those two lines and run `update-grub` again. I recommend not modifying anything else, unless you know what you're doing...

Answer (score 1):

You can hold down the (right) shift key while booting, before the elementary logo appears to get the Grub menu displayed.